# In Python, how do I make a temp file that persists until the next run?

Tags: python, temporary-files

I need to create a folder that I use only once, but need to have it exist until the next run. It seems like I should be using the tmp_file module in the standard library, but I'm not sure how to get the behavior that I want.

Currently, I'm doing the following to create the directory:

```
randName = "temp" + str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
os.makedirs(randName)
```

And when I want to delete the directory, I just look for a directory with "temp" in it.
This seems like a dirty hack, but I'm not sure of a better way at the moment.

Incidentally, the reason that I need the folder around is that I start a process that uses the folder with the following:

```
subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True).pid
```

and then quit my script to let the other process finish the work.

Comment: "This seems like a dirty hack"?  Why?  If you did it in the shell or in another language, you'd do the same thing.  Please detail what you don't like about this solution.

Comment: hmmm, I'm not sure. I guess it felt like the sort of thing that a real Pythonista would have a cleaner way to do.  
The part that really feels dirty is the deleting....

Comment: Again -- why?  What's wrong with deleting a file (or directory) that you're no longer using.  Technically, the "consumer" of that directory should delete when it's finished.  But what's wrong with cleanup?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Creating the folder with a 4-digit random number is insecure, and you also need to worry about collisions with other instances of your program.

A much better way is to create the folder using [`tempfile.mkdtemp`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html), which does exactly what you want (i.e. the folder is not deleted when your script exits). You would then pass the folder name to the second Popen'ed script as an argument, and it would be responsible for deleting it.

Answer (score 8):

What you've suggested is dangerous.  You may have race conditions if anyone else is trying to create those directories -- including other instances of your application.  Also, deleting anything containing "temp" may result in deleting more than you intended.  As others have mentioned, [tempfile.mkdtemp](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) is probably the safest way to go.  Here is an example of what you've described, including launching a subprocess to use the new directory.

```
import tempfile
import shutil
import subprocess

d = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='tmp')
try:
    subprocess.check_call(['/bin/echo', 'Directory:', d])
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(d)
```

Answer (score 4):

"I need to create a folder that I use only once, but need to have it exist until the next run."

"Incidentally, the reason that I need the folder around is that I start a process ..."

Not incidental, at all.  Crucial.

It appears you have the following design pattern.

```
mkdir someDirectory
proc1 -o someDirectory # Write to the directory
proc2 -i someDirectory # Read from the directory
if [ %? == 0 ]
then
    rm someDirectory
fi
```

Is that the kind of thing you'd write at the shell level?

If so, consider breaking your Python application into to several parts.

- The parts that do the real work ("proc1" and "proc2")
- A Shell which manages the resources and processes; essentially a Python replacement for a bash script.

Answer (score 3):

A temporary file is something that lasts for a single program run.

What you need is not, therefore, a temporary file.

Also, beware of multiple users on a single machine - just deleting anything with the 'temp' pattern could be anti-social, doubly so if the directory is not located securely out of the way.

Also, remember that on some machines, the `/tmp` file system is rebuilt when the machine reboots.

Comment: yea, I think I need a temporary-ish file. It really does only exist for one run, but the run continues after my script ends.

Answer (score 3):

You can also automatically register an function to completely remove the temporary directory on any exit (with or without error) by doing :

```
import atexit
import shutil
import tempfile

# create your temporary directory
d = tempfile.mkdtemp()

# suppress it when python will be closed
atexit.register(lambda: shutil.rmtree(d))

# do your stuff...
subprocess.Popen([command], shell=True).pid
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing atexit: https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html Wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

`tempfile` is just fine, but to be on a safe side you'd need to safe a directory name somewhere until the next run, for example pickle it. then read it in the next run and delete directory. and you are not required to have `/tmp` for the root, `tempfile.mkdtemp` has an optional `dir` parameter for that. by and large, though, it won't be different from what you're doing at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of creating the temporary file name is either using tempName.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b', suffix='.tmp', prifix='someRandomNumber' dir=None)
or u can use mktemp() function.

The mktemp() function will not actually create any file, but will provide a unique filename (actually does not contain PID).